# Firebase join without subscription

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to join two tables in Firebase Firestore DB. Do do so, I have to get a value from collection 'attendees' and then perform a `forEach` to recover the event data in collection 'event', pushing it into an array and then return the array in a promise.

I am using `.valueChanges().subscribe()`. What happens here is, if I add a new event for this attendee, the subscription works and push the data into the array again.

What I need to know, is how with join table work. Is there any way to perform the forEach with no subscription?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

This is my collection combination to perform the join

```
findByUserUid(user_uid: string) {
    let events: any[] = [];
    console.log(events);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log(events);

      this.db
        .collection('attendees', ref => ref.where('user_uid', '==', user_uid))
        .snapshotChanges()
        .subscribe((attendeesSnaps: any) => {
          events = [];
          attendeesSnaps.forEach((attendeeSnapshot: any) => {
            this.db
              .collection('events')
              .doc(attendeeSnapshot.payload.doc.data().event_uid)
              .valueChanges()
              .subscribe((event: any) => {
                console.log(events);
                event.uid = attendeeSnapshot.payload.doc.data().event_uid;
                events.push(event);
                console.log('pushing', event);
              });
          });
        });
      console.log('all events', events);

      resolve(events);
    });
  }
```

When collection 'attendees' is updated (adding a new attendee to -this- event), the foreach is perfom again and I got duplicate data in `events` array (which is returned again because of the subscription).

I need to avoid this duplicate data to be returned in every collection update.

**EDIT 2**

I've fixed the issue. Using `.ref.get()` works fine! Here is my final version of the method (if it can be improved, please let me know :) )

```
findByUserUid(user_uid: string) {
    const events: any[] = [];

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.db
        .collection('attendees')
        .ref.where('user_uid', '==', user_uid)
        .get()
        .then((attendeesSnaps: any) => {
          attendeesSnaps.forEach((attendeeSnapshot: any) => {
            this.db
              .collection('events')
              .doc(attendeeSnapshot.data().event_uid)
              .ref.get()
              .then((eventSnap: any) => {
                const event = eventSnap.data();
                event.uid = eventSnap.id;
                events.push(event);
              })
              .catch(err => {
                reject(err);
              });
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          reject(err);
        });
      resolve(events);
    });
  }
```

Comment: There are no join operations in Firestore.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I am combining the data of two collections. Maybe, I've done my question in the wrong way.